# [mntent]: line 16 in /etc/fstab is bad

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

I am try to `mount -a` my hard disc. But end up I got this respond

```
root@server:~# mount -a
[mntent]: line 16 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 18 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 20 in /etc/fstab is bad
[mntent]: line 22 in /etc/fstab is bad
```

Below is my `blkid` and `fstab` information.

May I know how should I fix it?

```
root@server:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="2c5e3f03-9c84-45ce-8b66-250b2ee16f18" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="4fbcae12-a919-498e-8eb5-43cd60ef939d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="ef042524-6d80-430f-980a-fb658362f8fa" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2bc1aa0c-ccb1-4f12-89c5-0bfa56f43ddf" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="b6eb5a17-f4b8-45ba-bdfb-34c6f15198b7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="GMS Backup" UUID="d33007ad-90e0-42d5-9c51-0e1999c18f00" TYPE="ext4" 


# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2c5e3f03-9c84-45ce-8b66-250b2ee16f18 /               ext4    errors=remoun$
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=4fbcae12-a919-498e-8eb5-43cd60ef939d /home           ext4    defaults     $
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=516752cc-4617-4016-a8cb-93979d289241 none            swap    sw           $
# /media was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=2bc1aa0c-ccb1-4f12-89c5-0bfa56f43ddf /media           ext4    defaults    $
# /media was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=b6eb5a17-f4b8-45ba-bdfb-34c6f15198b7 /media           ext4    defaults    $
# /media was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=ef042524-6d80-430f-980a-fb658362f8fa /media           ext4    defaults    $
# /media was on /dev/sde1 during installation
UUID=d33007ad-90e0-42d5-9c51-0e1999c18f00 /media           ext4    defaults    $
```

Much appreciate in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `$` signs at the end of every line? Output artifact? Try removing them.

Comment: I suspect the `$` characters are just line-ending / wrapping markers from whatever program the OP is viewing the file in (I think `nano` does this by default). The **real** issue seems to me the attempt to mount multiple devices (as indicated by the different UUIDs) to the same mountpoint, /media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't have multiple different block devices (as indicated by the different UUIDs) mounted to the same filesystem mountpoint `/media` (at least not without some kind of overlay filesystem).

You would need to create separate mountpoints such as `/media/disk1`, `/media/disk2` and so on, and then modify your fstab file to something like

```
# /media was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=2bc1aa0c-ccb1-4f12-89c5-0bfa56f43ddf /media/disk1           ext4    defaults
# /media was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=b6eb5a17-f4b8-45ba-bdfb-34c6f15198b7 /media/disk2           ext4    defaults
# /media was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=ef042524-6d80-430f-980a-fb658362f8fa /media/disk3           ext4    defaults
# /media was on /dev/sde1 during installation
UUID=d33007ad-90e0-42d5-9c51-0e1999c18f00 /media/disk4           ext4    defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/fstab` and delete all those `$` at the end of the lines.

Comment: I didn't copy it. He posted his comment in between me editing the original post and posting my own answer. I also notice that his edit has taken prioriy over mine. I guess I was too slow.

Comment: i removed those $ still doesnt solve the issue.